# Suggestions about proper usage of vk-200 choke

Tags: power-supply, ferrite, emi-filtering, hf, power-filtering

I have an old custom-built non-switching 5V power supply (usual 220V-12V transformer + bridge + 7805 regulator + various capacitors) that I'm using to power a HF upconverter and a HF LNA.

I'm currently fighting RFI/EMI and trying to place ferrites in all possible places to reduce/eliminate the disturbance I'm getting.
If I correctly remember, it should be good to use VK-200 chokes in series on the 5V power line.

Does anyone have a schematic / text or suggestions about the proper placement? I still have at least 20 of those VK-200 and I would be happy to use them.

The chokes are of this kind (axial 2.5 turns):

[image: http://www.rf-microwave.com/schede/images/00002637.jpg]

Adding the power supply schematic:
[image]

Comment: What are the places (indicate on the schematic) where you already tried placing ferrites?

Comment: Hi. I just realized that i've been a bit ambiguous in the text. I had RFI / EMI. i placed ferrites on coax and solved about RFI. I didn't previously try VK200 in any specific place. Adding them as indicated seems to have helped a lot with noise coming through my mains cable (I think). I still have some noise apparently sweeping or repeating in some way with a frequency going between 15 and 30 MHz and I'm working to find the better grounding options as suggested by Marla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on the VK-200 can be found [At this link](http://www.rf-microwave.com/en/shop/0/220-vk200-inductors/2637-VK200-2.html)

> VK200 inductor with 2½ turns, suitable for HF, VHF e UHF, for > 7 MHz frequencies.  Impedance: 280Ω at 10 MHz

From the above information the inductance can be calculated to be about 4.4 uHy.

You did say it was for HF (high frequency), which might be anything from 80 meters to 10 meters). You haven't mentioned what frequencies you are trying to filter.

You could make a simple filter for your 5 volts as follows
**EDIT**  : added C6, C7, and Earth Ground :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWU7H0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I chose capacitor values that might work for you. Better design could be made if there were particular frequencies to filter.

I haven't shown any filters to earth since I don't know your power supply nor your up converter earth ground situations.

**ADDED** after first 3 comments : Making sure to show difference between Earth Gnd and GND (power supply common).
You can also use shielded cable from the 5 volt power supply (the filter built into the power supply). The shielded cable should have only ONE end of the shield connected to Earth Gnd. Connecting to Earth Gnd at both ends creates a ground loop which can pick up additional noise. Perhaps connect the shield to your metal box upconverter and then the upconverter box (enclosure) is to Earth Gnd.

Look at your entire system and see if there are multiple Earth Gnd connections which are causing ground loops.  Try to design for a single point connection to Earth in your entire system.

Comment: Thank you Marla for your kind answer. I will try asap the filter you designed. About the power supply and up-converter ground: I've enclosed the power supply in a aluminum box and circuit ground is connected to the box. Same for the up-converter. I'm adding ferrites on the 220V ac cable and proper type on the coax at the antenna side. I will add the power supply diagram to the question after posting this comment. I'm doing radio-astronomy experiments between 15 and 30 MHz but I'm getting all sort of noise...

Comment: i guess from FM (adding a filter before the LNA), WiFi routers and probably the Raspberry PI clock (using that to process the radio data). Other sources could be the R-PI power supply (switched one, trying to shield it in some way).

Comment: i would like to add some example spectrograms about the noise I'm receiving but I don't have enough "reputation" to add more than 2 links :-(

Comment: I have made edits to the answer after your first 3 comments. Schematic diagram was updated with Earth Gnd.

Comment: Thank you Marla for your update. I've built the filter. Hope to test and measure noise again during this weekend.